# Theme support with assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following project structure:

```
/app
/config
/db
...
/themes
  /default
    /assets
      /images
      /stylesheets
      /...
    /views
      /...
  /theme1
   /assets
     /...
   /views
     /...
```

'default' theme should be used by default :). 'theme1' - should override any, eg logo.png or view (application.erb).

It should work in this way: try to get asset from 'theme1' if absent - use from 'default'.

Pretty simple with views:

```
self.prepend_view_path ::ActionView::FileSystemResolver.new(theme_view_path_for(name))
self.prepend_view_path ::ActionView::FileSystemResolver.new(default_theme_path)
```

But i cant resolve it with assets.

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/themes/default/assets/stylesheets"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/themes/default/assets/images"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/themes/default/assets/javascript"
```

This adds assets as usual, eg asset can be accessed with url 'assets/logo.png', but i need prefixed one - "assets/theme1/logo.png".
Also if 'theme1' doesnt override logo.png by "assets/theme1/logo.png" url should 'default' theme logo returned. (Similar to above with views).

I have tried themes_for_rails - but it doesnt fit, because they override whole assets structure (own controller for serving, etc).

Also, it would be great to have ability to hook into assets resolve,
when accessing logo1.png, it should be possible to serve it with my controller and return it from database, for example.

Thanks for any advice, i'll share with results when finish.

Kirill Salykin

Answer (score 0):

By default the folders in the first level will be ignored by Sprocket in rails. You can verify this in a default app, where you see the compiled files missing the initial javascripts/ images/ or stylesheets/ folders.

A better structure for you would be:

```
/themes
  /stylesheets
    /default
    /theme1
  /images
    /default
    /theme1
```

Then add the directory as so:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/stylesheets"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/images"
```

Want to reference the files in a theme?

```
= image_tag("#{theme_name}/background.png")
= stylesheet_tag("#{theme_name}/application.css")
```

That should work.